# compare two arrays and filter the duplicates out in a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am stuck on this problem. I have two arrays (simplified here)

```
const array1 = [1,2,3]
const array2 = [1,2]
```

I want to create a new array comparing the similar values between them and removing them so the final array would be

```
const finalArray = [3]
```

I have tried this among many other combinations of mapping filtering, for loops, I don't remember what else I've tested hence only have this too post

```
var finalArray = array1.filter(function (e) {
      return array2.indexOf(e) > -1;
    });
```

The result of this is just

```
[1,2]

Hoping someone can point out a solution, I'm sure it's obvious, but I am scratching my head at this point
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just messed up the meaning of the test, and your code should be:

```
array1.filter(function (e) { return array2.indexOf(e) === -1 })
```

but for this kind of case it is better to use the [array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method
(and in the case of an array made of objects use the [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method)

```js
const array1 = [1,2,3]
const array2 = [1,2]

const finalArray = array1.filter(x=>!array2.includes(x))

console.log( finalArray )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a douplicate question to [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Check out [Luis Sieira's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034768/4994136) for all possible set theory solutions

Answer (score -1):

You could also use a `Set` to remove duplicate values.

Spread both of your arrays into a combined array to form a set. Then spread your `Set` back into an array to have an array with only unique values.

```
const array1 = [1,2,3]
const array2 = [1,2]

const deduped = [...new Set([...array1, ...array2])]
```

Comment: seen you didn't read that  : " filter the duplicates **out** "  or " and removing them "